# Inserting ActionListener's into GUI code for Java

Tags: java, user-interface

Alright, I tried this on CodeReview, but no one responded.  I am an eight grader with a school project on finding the total permutations of two numbers.  I have the guts of it done, but I want to incorporate GUI.  And to use GUI, I need ActionListener's.  The catch is, I don't know how to use ActionListener's.  Any ideas?  Note that if you want the code, I can post it.

Thank You!!!!

Comment: Read the swing tutorial. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/ And Google is your friend.

Comment: *"I have the guts of it done, but I want to incorporate GUI."*  My advice is, devote extra time to ensuring your code is easy to read, well documented, and bug free.  Putting time into making a GUI for it is not what the homework is about, and won't seem as impressive as you suspect.

Comment: Thank you for that, @AndrewThompson, I have it completely bug-free (I think), seeing as it works for all positive numbers, even 1 and 2.  But I do get your point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Swing Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) is your friend - [How to Write an Action Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html).

Comment: Thank you, that was a major help!  +1

Answer (score 1):

Wrtiting an ActionListener is very simple. For example:

```
Button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // Do something here
            }
        });
```

Read more on event listeners [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html).